# Configure code folding in Atom to mimic PatentStorm

Tags: atom-editor, keymapping

In PatentStorm, I used <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd></kbd> — <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd></kbd> to fold / unfold code.

I migrated to Atom — is this possible to mimic?

Comment: Guys, **this question is NOT off-topic** as the tool in question is primarily for programming.

Comment: Did you ever try my solution?

Answer (score 0):

### Custom Keymap

Add this to your keymaps:

```
'atom-text-editor':
  'ctrl-w': 'editor:fold-current-row'
  'ctrl-shift-w': 'editor:unfold-current-row'
```

[Atom Keymaps In-Depth](https://flight-manual.atom.io/behind-atom/sections/keymaps-in-depth/#platform-windows)

---

#### Atom Defaults (Windows)

> You can fold blocks of code by clicking the arrows that appear when
>   you hover your mouse cursor over the gutter. You can also fold and
>   unfold from the keyboard with the <kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd></kbd> and <kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd></kbd> keybindings.

[Atom Code Folding](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/folding/#platform-windows)

#### Single Key Fold-Toggling

If you'd like to use a key binding to fold-toggle, create a custom command:

> ```
> atom.commands.add 'atom-text-editor',
>   'editor:toggle-current-row-folding': (event) ->
>     editor = @getModel()
>     bufferRow = editor.bufferPositionForScreenPosition(editor.getCursorScreenPosition()).row
>     if editor.isFoldedAtBufferRow(bufferRow)
>       editor.unfoldBufferRow(bufferRow)
>     else
>       editor.foldBufferRow(bufferRow)
> ```

Here you would use `'editor:toggle-current-row-folding'` as your command.

From abe + kschaper @ [How to toggle current fold in editor view?](https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-to-toggle-current-fold-in-editor-view/11094)